# MongoDB Replica Set: Disk size difference in Primary and Secondary Nodes

Tags: mongodb, replication

I just did the mongodb replica set configuration and all looks good. All data moved to secondary nodes properly. But when I looked at the data directory, I can see Primary have ~140G of data and at the same time secondary has only ~110G.

Did anyone come across this kind of issue while setting up the Replica Set. Is that something normal behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do an initial sync from scratch on a secondary, it writes all the data fresh.  This removes padding, empty space (deleted data) etc.  As a result, in that respect it is similar to running a repair.

If you ran a repair on the primary (blocking operation, only to be done if absolutely necessary), then the two would be far closer overall.

If you check the output from `db.stats()` you should see that the various databases have the same object count, the data directory size differences are nothing to be worried about.

Comment: There is anything we can do to optimize the db periodically, without affecting the production environment?

Comment: @geek Hmm not sure, you would have to post a db.stats() but maybe power of 2 sizes allocation might help, afterall I would say the 28GB (taking 2GB of pre-alloc into account) might be from moving documents.

Comment: Besides what Sammaye mentions (usePowerOf2Sizes is less efficient initially but will be more effective if you move/delete a lot) then a full replica set gives you options.  Take one secondary out of the set, run a repair or do a full resync, then repeat until you have done all nodes in the set (with a primary step down at some point).  That would allow you to periodically recover space without a large impact (there is always the short blip for an election to consider).