# Mongodb replica set: Database Size Difference

Tags: mongodb, replication

What are the possible reasons for a difference in database size in primary and secondary nodes of a MongoDB replica set.
In my setup, the Secondary node database is of higher size than the primary one. Both nodes have the same number of objects, but the values of "avgObjSize", "dataSize", "storageSize" are  higher for secondary node. 
There is no replication lag as well, as checked from rs.stats()

What can I check?

Comment: are you using different version of mongodb?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843229/mongodb-replica-set-disk-size-difference-in-primary-and-secondary-nodes

Comment: I have to frank, the answers below would make sense if the secondary was smaller than the primary but it is not as such they do not. Can you show us some actual stats like db.collection.stats() and rs.stats()?

Comment: I recently converted our MongoDB to a replica-set and was concerned by the smaller size reported by the Secondary (117GB v. 106 GB). However, the data is all perfectly well and complete. As others have mentioned the culprit can largely be attributed to differences in padding-factor and indexes. Further things to consider are the underlying configuration of each instance - are they on different types of drives, FS formatting, block-sizes. In my case we have a primary on a Raid array and a secondary on an equally sized single drive on a separate machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Brief:**
Because of different amount of not reclaimed memory space on secondary and different padding factor on secondary and primary.

**Long:**
It could be the case if you have long running primary node where some documents were deleted and inserted, and no compact operation was run. This space would no be reclaimed, and would be counted in dataSize, avgObjSize and storageSize. Secondary could be fully resynced from primary, but only operations from current oplog would be replayed. In this case secondary could have lower values for dataSize, avgObjSize and storageSize. If after that secondary is elected as primary, you could see described difference in sizes. In addition each server has it's own padding factor, that is why you see difference in dataSize.

Concrete scenario could be different, but there are two main causes: amount of not reclaimed memory space and different padding factor.

Comment: @Sammaye In general I agree with you, but secondary and primary are not permanent states. Secondary could be elected as primary, then secondary would have larger numbers.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. Yes, the Padding factor for a Collection is higher in Secondary node than the Primary node. I will check/confirm if this Node earlier server as the Primary.

Comment: True but it would be a lucky guess to state that primary has changed

Comment: Ah hang on I see you mention that in your answer, ok kool

Comment: Is there any official documentation where I can read more about this?

Comment: I did not find any information related to this here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync

Answer (score 0):

There's a concept [padding factor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-padding) may be the cause. MongoDB leaves some space for the future updating, so that when the size of object grows, you don't always have to move the object to another storage space.
padding factor can be found in your collections stats:

```
db.colname.stats()
```

a sample result:

```
{
"ns" : "merchant.product",
"count" : 24,
"size" : 23168,
"avgObjSize" : 965.3333333333334,
"storageSize" : 204800,
"numExtents" : 2,
"nindexes" : 1,
"lastExtentSize" : 163840,
"paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000000053,
"systemFlags" : 1,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 8176,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 8176
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

When you update your collection, mongodb changes the value paddingFactor. So there might be slight difference between your 2 nodes because they may not be created at the same time.

When your "padding" doesn't satisfy the new size of your object, mongodb moves it to another storage space. Then the original space is spared for future usage and the object occupies a new block of space. However, this behavior maybe different in your 2 nodes, too because of the different padding factor.

So the size is generally OK.